# Is there any way to send/see parameters in a crash?

Tags: ios, crashlytics

When I see my iOS app crashes in the online tool, I see the stack trace, but I don't see the parameters values. Is there any way to see it? It is difficult to reproduce a bug if I don't have the data that caused that bug.
I know a possibility could be to add extra fields or CLS_LOG, but for doing that I should deploy a new version and wait until the crash happens again. It seems not a good solution.
Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't.  The accepted way is to reproduce the crash within your development environment where you can examine the variables within the debugger.

You can generally infer the value of some of the variables, however, based on the exception text and the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io). It has a tool called Crashlytics. It will show you what line crashed in your code.

You can then try and reproduce the error in code and fix it with more ease! I hope this helps!

Comment: The OP is using Crashlytics.  Check the tags.

Comment: @Droppy Oops. Sorry there. So… No, you cannot see the parameters that crashed your code in Crashlytics. You'll have to try and recreate the crash in code.